# change return type in AWS Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying out AWS Lambda.

I have enabled Lambda proxy integration.

When I try to query the endpoint with a post request  I get an internal server error.

However if I were to do it in Javascript I get the response as a string.

The function is as follows:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    // TODO implement
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {'Control-Access-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: {
            event,
            context,
        }
    };
    return response;
};
```

Comment: *do it in javascript* - what do you mean by this?

Comment: can you try stringifying the body? ... `body: JSON.stringify({event, context})`

Comment: @ttulka make a XML request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your body should be a string, not an object:

```
const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {'Control-Access-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify({
        event,
        context,
    })
};
return response;
```

Then you can take a look at CloudWatch log to see what the problem is.

Comment: This solves the problem in the testing area in api gateway. But still when i send a XML request to the endpoint.... I get back the response as a string and not a object...

Comment: @uvic Unfortunately, the body is always a string, you have to parse it on the client side, that's correct so.

Answer (score 0):

If you have checked lambda proxy integration you need this format as a responce

```
{
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(message),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
}
```

The returned object must have a statusCode, body, and headers attribute. In my example above, I included Content-Type in the headers object, but it can be empty if you’d like. body’s value must be a string, if we were to pass in the user object here without turning it into a JSON-encoded string, this would fail.

If your return object doesn’t have these attributes, when you test the Lambda-API Gateway connection an error like this will pop up:

```
message: "Internal server error".
```

If you uncheck the lambda proxy integration you can pass whatever you want as a responce.